# bash psql Insert error 127

Tags: bash, postgresql, psql, dml

I am new to `psql`. In `bash` script I am trying to insert a row using `psql`. The row is actually getting inserted but I am getting error message. Please help.

Essential part of the code:

```
L_SQL="INSERT INTO consumer.RAKESH_TEST(num_col1, text_col2) VALUES(2,'TWO');"

  `psql -t -h ${HOSTNAME} -d ${SRCDATABASE} -U ${SRCUSER} -v "ON_ERROR_STOP=1" <<EOF
  ${L_SQL}
  \q
EOF`

SQL_ERROR=$?
```

I am getting following message:

```
./psql.sh: line 146: INSERT: command not found
SQL_ERROR=127
```

Comment: You should not put everything in backticks.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz! Error was eliminated with your suggestion.